# Terraform script to check the condition

Tags: azure, terraform

I have big terraform script . By end of the script there is a code block which takes backup of the VM, But I dont want to take backup of test VMs. I just need main VMs backup. Is there any script in terraform to check the VM then proceed to backup script.

```
resource "Azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "db"
  Count                          = var.db-nodecount
  resource_group_name            = var.mgmtrg.name
  recovery_vault_name            = var.mgmtrv.name
  source_vm_id                   = element(azurerm_virtual_machine.db.*.id, count.index)
  backup_policy_id               = var.db-policy.id
  lifecycle{
    ignore_changes = [
      backup_policy_id,
      recovery_vault_name,
      tags
     ]
  }
}
```

Image for logs[![Image for logs][1]][1]

Comment: Some code of what you are doing would be nice...

Comment: @HelderSepulveda. I have attached the code.Please check and suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `backup_policy_id` is required:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/backup_protected_vm.html#backup_policy_id

In that case I would add a few more vars to address your concerns with test VM's
Something like:

```
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "db"
  count               = var.db-nodecount
  resource_group_name = var.mgmtrg.name
  recovery_vault_name = var.mgmtrv.name
  source_vm_id        = element(azurerm_virtual_machine.db.*.id, count.index)
  backup_policy_id    = var.env == "tst" ? var.db-tst-policy.id : var.db-policy.id
}
```

Just have to create a test backup_policy (`azurerm_backup_policy_vm`) that takes a backup maybe once every 100 years

---

Another option could be not create the `azurerm_backup_protected_vm` at all:

```
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "db"
  count                = var.env == "tst" ? 0 : var.db-nodecount
  resource_group_name  = var.mgmtrg.name
  recovery_vault_name  = var.mgmtrv.name
  source_vm_id         = element(azurerm_virtual_machine.db.*.id, count.index)
  backup_policy_id     = var.db-policy.id
}
```

Comment: In My case  there is variable  called "env". In my pipeline if i give env = tst. Then only backup shouldnt  take.. How can I declare that cammand.Please help

Comment: I updated my answer to use your env variable `var.env == "tst"` you can read more about it here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Where I can I check to know is the VMs got backup or not? After running the script

Comment: I have added image of output logs in my question..In that its showing azurerm_backup_protected_vm is still creating

Comment: we have given env in form of files like dev.tfvars ,prd.tfvars, tst.tfvars. In this case how can we define the condition